# Ruby, can you call a method from inside the same method?

Tags: ruby, methods

I'm trying to compare 2 files. If only 1 file appears, it will create a copy. 
Is it then possible to re-call the method, when using `begin..rescue..end`?

```
def differ()
begin
  file_today = read_file("/etc/hosts.deny")
  file_yesterday = read_file("/etc/hosts.deny_old")
  content = Diffy::Diff.new(file_yesterday, file_today)
rescue
  copy_log
  differ #call itself?!O_o Well, after the copy has been created!
end
  return content
end
```

It is "differ #call itself?!O_o Well, after the copy has been created!" that I cant get to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `retry` keyword in your rescue clause to restart it.

Edit: Here's some more information from the free edition of [Programming Ruby:](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html)

"The redo statement causes a loop to repeat the current iteration. Sometimes, though, you need to wind the loop right back to the very beginning. The retry statement is just the ticket. retry restarts any kind of iterator loop. Retry will reevaluate any arguments to the iterator before restarting it."

Edit: I realized that this behavior for retry has been deprecated in 1.9. Just know that retry is usually used to re-execute a code block that raised an exception. Make sure you've fixed whatever caused the exception before you retry - otherwise you end up in an infinite loop!

Comment: You're very welcome :) Check out my edit, I linked to a good resource for learning about `retry` and `redo`. Mark my answer as correct if you're satisfied with it!

Comment: I appreciate your answer and edit:> The "copy_log" is what should fix the exception. I would like to upvote you but i have no reputation on stackoverflow :/